# Can't find CSRF token as i try to send POST data thru a link in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, post, yii, csrf

for the shopping cart i add 'add to cart' link. Through adding a 'click' event i make it a POST request. 
The system replies: 'Can't find the csrf token';
Here is the code:

```
 'add to cart' => array(
               'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("assortment/addtocart", array("id"=>$data[id], "YII_CSRF_TOKEN" => ' . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken. ', "csrf"=>' . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . ' ))', 

               'click'=>"function(){
                            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('assortment-grid', { 
                                type:'POST',
                                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                            //  data:{YII_CSRF_TOKEN: " . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . "},
                                /*success:function(data) {
                                      $.fn.yiiGridView.update('assortment-grid'); 
                                }*/
                            })
                            return false;
                          }
                        ",
                    ),
```

I've added the 'csrf' parameter into the link. 
When i uncomment `data:{YII_CSRF_TOKEN: " . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . "},` the POST request becomes simple GET redirect (csrf validated).
I do not need to update grid, so i've commented out `success:function(data)`.
Since there should not be redirection, i need to keep the request POST and ajax.
You might look at screenshots of the POST form:
[image]
[image]

**How to fix it? Can i pass csrf as a POST parameter? Can i add a POST submit button into CGridView?**

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have this code in config

```
return array(
    'components'=>array(
        'request'=>array(
            'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
        ),
    ),
);
```

add token as hidden input(if needed):

```
$request = Yii:app()->getRequest();
echo CHtml::textField($request->csrfTokenName, $request->getCsrfToken());
```

and send all form data

```
data: $('#formId').serialize()
```

Comment: **Fhe first reqirement is met** ` 'enableCsrfValidation'=>true`
**The second**: as i add `$request =...` after the Grid and brasket Grid and this csrf parameter field with `CHtml::Form();  ... CHtml::endForm();` - this parameter is NOT being passed in POST. I guess this link with 'click' event is not the form's submit button.
**As soon as i add** `data: ... ` in JS the POST becomes GET request.

Comment: `'click'=>"js:function(){`

Comment: i've corrected and it's still the same thing. 
Now i have this:
     
      'click'=>"js:function(){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('assortment-grid', { 
         type:'POST',
         url:$(this).attr('href'),
         data['YII_CSRF_TOKEN'] = ". Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . ";
        });
        return false;
         }
       ",